# How do I store a new array all checked data from a table in REACT?

Tags: reactjs

```
const students = [
    { _id: 1, name: "Ahmed Ali" },
    { _id: 2, name: "John Doe" },
    { _id: 3, name: "Jane Doe" },
    { _id: 4, name: "Farah Gedi" },
    { _id: 5, name: "Mustafa Jama" }
]

const attendCheck = ({ target: { name, value, id } }) => {
 // logics will go here...
}
```

I returned this table with students data

```
<table className='table table-sm hover bordered striped'>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>STD ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th> </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {students &&
    students.map((std) => (
      <tr key={std._id}>
        <td>{std.name}</td>
        <td>
          <input
            className='form-check-input me-1'
            type='checkbox'
            id={`${std._id}`}
            name={`${std.name}`}
            onChange={(e) => attendCheck(e)}
            value={std._id}
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    ))}
</tbody>
</table>
```

As you see above it has checkboxes input. I want to store all checked data in a new array, how do I do that?.

NB. students data it's not real data, I'm fetching the data from server so it can be any length.

Comment: you want store full data of student or only id?

Comment: I want to store only ID or ID with Name it's same, I want to get the concept to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want store only id student, you can add a state is array to store selected id student:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
const attendCheck = ({ target: { name, value, id } }) => {
  if (!selected.includes(id)) {
    setSelected((prevSelected) => [...prevSelected, id]);
  } else {
    setSelected((prevSelected) =>
      prevSelected.filter((stdId) => stdId!== id)
    );
  }
}
```